# Matlab removing unwanted numbers from array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have got a matlab script from net which generates even numbers from an inital value. this is the code.

```
n = [1 2 3 4 5 6];
iseven = [];
for i = 1: length(n);
if rem(n(i),2) == 0
iseven(i) = i;
else iseven(i) = 0;
end
end
iseven
```

and its results is this

```
iseven =

     0     2     0     4     0     6
```

in the result i am getting both even numbers and zeros, is there any way i can remove the zeros and get a result like this

```
iseven =

         2    4     6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To display only non-zero results, you can use [`nonzeros`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html)

```
iseven = [0     2     0     4     0     6]

nonzeros(iseven)

ans =

     2     4     6
```

Comment: Neat, didn't know about `nonzeros`.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain such vector without the loop you have:

```
n(rem(n, 2)==0)
ans =

 2     4     6
```

However, if you already have a vector with zeros and non-zeroz, uou can easily remove the zero entries using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
iseven = iseven(find(iseven));
```

`find` is probably one of the most frequently used matlab functions. It returns the indices of non-zero entries in vectors and matrices:

```
% indices of non-zeros in the vector
idx = find(iseven);
```

You can use it for obtaining row/column indices for matrices if you use two output arguments:

```
% row/column indices of non-zero matrix entries
[i,j] = find(eye(10));
```

Answer (score 3):

The code you downloaded seems to be a long-winded way of computing the range

```
2:2:length(n)
```

If you want to return only the even values in a vector called `iseven` try this expression:

```
iseven(rem(iseven,2)==0)
```

Finally, if you really want to remove `0`s from an array, try this:

```
iseven = iseven(iseven~=0)
```

Comment: why the find(), why not iseven(iseven==0) = []... or iseven = iseven(iseven~=0) if performance is an issue?

Comment: Good questions @Dan.  Go ahead and edit the answer for improved goodness.

Comment: @Dan: I made the edit you suggested, your own attempt seemed to get trapped in review and I couldn't figure out how to approve it.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of the vector whenever you find what you're looking for.

```
n = [1 2 3 4 5 6]; 
iseven = []; % has length 0
for i = 1: length(n);
  if rem(n(i),2) == 0
    iseven = [iseven i]; % append to the vector 
  end
end
iseven
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the all Zeros from  the program we can use the following command,and the command is-

```
iseven(iseven==0)=[]
```